# How to drop the neo4j embedded database with java?

Tags: neo4j

The class `GraphDatabaseService` seems not provide any method to drop/clear the database. It there any other means to drop/clear the current embedded database with Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just perform a [GraphDatabaseService.shutdown()](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#shutdown%28%29) and after it has returned, remove the database files (using code like [this](https://github.com/neo4j/graphdb/blob/master/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/ImpermanentGraphDatabase.java#L83)).

You could also use [getAllNodes()](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#getAllNodes%28%29) to iterate over all nodes, delete their relationships and the nodes themselves. Maybe avoid deleting the reference node.

If your use case is testing, then you could use the [ImpermanentGraphDatabase](https://github.com/neo4j/graphdb/blob/master/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/ImpermanentGraphDatabase.java), which will delete the database after shutdown.

To use ImpermanentGraphDatabase add the neo4j-kernel tests jar/dependency to your project. Look for the file with a name ending with "tests.jar" [on maven central](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/).

Comment: Is there any way besides deleting files?

Comment: See http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Testing_with_Neo4j#Use_the_ImpermanentGraphDatabase

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to delete a directory with neo4j database. I do it in my junit tests after running all tests. Here is a function I use where *file* is the neo4j directory:

```
public static void deleteFileOrDirectory( final File file ) {
    if ( file.exists() ) {
        if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
            for ( File child : file.listFiles() ) {
                deleteFileOrDirectory( child );
            }
        }
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

I think I found it on neo4j wiki. I have found in [this discussion](http://lists.neo4j.org/pipermail/user/2011-March/007196.html) another solution. You can use [Blueprint API](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/), which provide method clear.

Answer (score 1):

Like nawroth said, for testing you should use the ImpermanentGraphDatabase. It pretty much auto-fixes all your problems.

If you're not testing, there are two ways really. I generally have two methods available to me. One is the clearDB method, in which I recursively delete the DB path. I use the FileUtils library for this, and it's pretty much a single line of code :

```
FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
```

The other one is to remove every node in the database EXCEPT THE REFERENCE NODE, using the removeAllNodes method. There is a simple query for this, which you execute like this:

```
engine.execute("START n = node(*), ref = node(0)  WHERE n<>ref DELETE n");
```

Important to note is that you have to call the clearDB method BEFORE you create a new EmbeddedGraphDatabase object. The removeAllNodes method is called AFTER you've created this object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper class

```
Neo4jHelper.cleanDb(db);
```

(it comes from org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.node.Neo4jHelper and the db you reference is a GraphDatabaseService)

You also have the ability to dump it:

```
Neo4jHelper.dumpDb();
```